# how to make conditional fields work with MEDIA

Tags: 8

I installed conditional fields for drupal 8 and i made a field be invisible or visible depending on the choice of another field which is an entity reference.  but it doesn't work at all. It works for nodes , but not media.  Any idea how to make it work for media?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was giving an error on getType when it was a media object.
I fixed it by changing line 208 in conditional_fields.module to

```
if (method_exists($entity, 'getType')) {
      $bundle = $entity->bundle();
```

Comment: This very much sounds like https://www.drupal.org/node/2839354 which should have been fixed. Do submit a patch if it has not been fixed yet

Comment: its not the same thing.